# How to run a specific job with GithubActions

Tags: devops, github-actions, cicd

When some of my GithubActions jobs has failed, I don't have the possibility to re-run the specific failing job, only "Re-run all jobs". Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is all working now in GitHub, the caveat is you can only run "specific jobs in a workflow run up to 30 days after its initial run."

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs#reviewing-previous-workflow-runs

Answer (score 1):

I’m the workflow file you want to be able to manually trigger, add workflow_dispatch to the “on:” clause. Then go to the actions tab on github, select the action and you should see the option to manually run it. Before asking this type of question, please use google next time. When looking for “triggger github workflow manually” the first result is a article written by github on how to do it. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow

Comment: they asked how to trigger jobs, not workflows

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, re-run a single job is not possible yet.
Their repository does have an Open Issue to implement this feature.
https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/432

The good news is it is officially in their roadmap and is scheduled for Q1 2022.
https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/271